# Why is it bad to have arguments like bool throwException on public methods?

Tags: .net, exception

I usually use that kind of method (function) to test if conditions are valid :

```
Function IsShapeSelected(ByRef oShape As Object, Optional bThrowExc As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    'Detect if a shape is selected
    Dim bOk As Boolean
    'Test if shape (and return it byref) is selected (using Try Catch if necessary)
    'oShape = Cast (Selection..)
    'bOk = True/False 
    '
    If Not bOk And bThrowExc Then
        '...
        Throw New CMyProgException("No shape is selected...") 'Throw a localized error message..
    End If
    Return bOk
End Function
```

And use it like this :

```
Sub ExemplesOfMainMethodsUsinIt()
    Dim oShape As Object
    Try
        'Example1 :
        'If i want to display message in case shape is not selected
        If Not IsShapeSelected(oShape, True) Then Exit Sub
        '...continue process, ex rename shape,..
        'Example2 (supposed to be in another exemple procedure)
        'If i want to get the style of the shape for example
        Dim sStyle As String = If(IsShapeSelected(oShape, False), oShape.Style, "AnyDefaultStyle")
        '...continue process, ex: applystyle to all shapes..
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Display error message
    End Try

End Sub
```

I find it's pretty convenient but I've recently read (MSDN or in forums) :
It's not good to have arguments like bool throwException on public methods - referring to the ".NET Framework Design Guidelines" book.

But without any explanation on the reason...

Is it because the method is partially not clear (either return bool result or throw exception) and may be misused or for any other reason ?
(It may seem a simple question but it's a basic pattern of most of my method and i would prefer to avoid conception error..). Thanks.

UPDATE : Change name of method from TryShapeSelected to IsShapeSelected - TryShapeSelected let suppose there was a ShapeSelected method because of TryXXX pattern as Simon, Phil stated

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for flow control.

Comment: Your `TryShapeSelected` implies that the method will `Try` the routine, not fail and return a boolean success. `int.TryParse` is a good example of this, it tries to convert the string and returns true/false if that was successful.  A caller wouldn't expect this method to throw an exception written in this way.

Comment: @PhilCooper : thanks for your answer. i understand..

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Thanks also. I will investigate your answer but at first thought, it was my purpose : stop the flow control to display an error message to end user..

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer given by Jamiec, one reason, besides it merely being a convention, for not using such behaviour is that oftentimes the method might throw other exceptions for unrelated reasons.  So you have a `bool` `throwOnError` which can be set to `false`, but that will only turn off the throwing of some particular exception, with the result that you still need exception handling code.  This might be confusing for consumers of the method.

Perhaps the primary reason, however, is that methods should be seen as setting up a contract which specifies how they interact with consumers; part of that contract is the valid range of inputs expected and the behaviour given when input falls outside that range.  If you pass such a `throwOnError` into the method, you are effectively allowing that contract to change, not just from consumer to consumer, but potentially at runtime, which again, can lead to unreliable and more unmaintainable code (because of confusion or shortcut taking).

There is very brief discussion of the `Do`/`TryDo` pattern (in this case, Date parsing) which Jamiec speaks of here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009(v=vs.110).aspx

UPDATE: I should perhaps add, I didn't mean to denigrate the usefulness and power of convention; convention is itself a very powerful way of providing systems which are reliable, so perhaps my use of 'merely' in the first paragraph gives the wrong impression.  Nevertheless, sometimes there are additional reasons for adopting certain practices as conventions.

Comment: Thanks simon. I'v previously read the Do/TryDo pattern and tried to create a mix of the two method because i get over 100 method in my case. But i agree with you on the fact "methods should be seen as setting up a contract which specifies how they interact with consumers" and that this mix didnt fully respect it

Comment: Thanks again for your update. If we consider two native method of .Net Framework supposing to return an integer  : (Array).IndexOf and Integer.Parse(string). they behave differently : one return only value, the other may retun an integer or raise exception. So Does the function IsShapeSelected(i change the name since) in a way follow this lazy convention (.net Framework does not always follow the same convention). Maybe the Do not use bool throwException in Public Method in the guidelines are too alarming

Comment: Well I think it's okay to indicate error by returning null, or -1, say, or alternatively by throwing an exception.  But your question was about why it's bad to give the consumer the option of how the method would indicate the error, which is different again, and that is what's discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it bad to have arguments like bool throwException on public methods

Simply because it is not the convention of the design guidlines for .NET apps. That does not mean you *can't* do it, it just means that if you follow design conventions, then other programmers will thank you. Of course, this may not be relevant to your situation - but it might be in future. So get used to it now.

---

For completeness, the right way to do this is to have 2 versions of your method. `DoSomething` would throw an exception if it doesnt work. `TryDoSomething` would return a boolean, and *not* throw an exception if it fails.

Your code would look like

```
Function TryShapeSelected(ByRef oShape As Object) As Boolean
    'Detect if a shape is selected
    Dim bOk As Boolean
    'Test if shape is selected (using Try Catch if necessary)
    'bOk = True/False     '
    Return bOk
End Function

Function ShapeSelected(ByRef oShape As Object) 
    'Detect if a shape is selected
    'Test if shape is selected (using Try Catch if necessary)    
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. I clearly understant it's conventions and it gives a cleaner code. (I 'm a self auto developer and i miss some basic usage). Thanks again